# Re-routing from LoadBalancer to custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have installed prometheus-stack on EKS. When I configure each of the services as `LoadBalancer`, I get an AWS provided Classic LB.

1. The current LB for accessing Grafana is `http://******-******.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/`
2. I bought a domain on Route53 which is named as `www.companyname.link`.
3. Now I want to be able to re-route the requests sent to `www.grafana.companyname.link` to `http://******-******.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/`.
4. For this, I have created a record in the Hosted Zone page with values

```
Record details

Record name: grafana.companyname.link
Record type: A
Value: dualstack.******-******.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com.
Alias: Yes
TTL (seconds): -
Routing policy: Simple
```

Now when I try with `http://******-******.ap-south-1.elb.amazonaws.com/` I'm able to access grafana but if I try with `grafana.companyname.link`, I'm unable to access it.

What more needs to be done here ?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cloudfront is a good proxy for routing requests from domains to origins (in your case this being the loadbalancer).

Go to AWS Cloudfront.
Create a new distribution, set origin as your loadbalancer, alternate domain as [www.companyname.link](http://www.companyname.link). You can take control of routing configs through lambda functions in cloudfront as well. Here is a quick guide I found to insert as a supplement to this answer: https://www.wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/200_labs/200_cloudfront_for_web_application/1_config_cloudfront/

I have extensive experience with Cloudfront so let me know if you have any specific questions.

Comment: We are using the Route53 `A` record approach, I'm checking with my Architect on approval for CloudFront since it has a pricing model, they're evaluating it internally. So I need to get the solution for the Route53 idea meanwhile.